# Where to get the " Copy from REST or HTTP using OAuth template" to use Oauth?

Tags: oauth, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

Currently I'm following this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#use-oauth) to use Oauth to  copy data from REST connector into Azure Data Lake Storage in JSON format using OAuth. but I cannot find below temple in my temple gallery. I wonder where and how to get this temple ?

[image]

screenshot2:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the following screenshot shows, you can click Add new resource button, then click pipeline from template and you will find it.

[image]

Comment: I met another problem when I set for SinkDataset as screenshot 2.  it shows my account "adftutorialalex" EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures'.  it suggests t disable these account features. not sure where to disable these